batch rename files in command prompt (CMD) stripping first few digits
I have a bunch of files where I want to strip the FIRST 4 digits from a file name.
for example:

a123hallo.txt > hallo.txt
a123you.txt > you.txt
a123all.txt > all.txt

This I prefer to do at the command prompt
(because I am not able to use PowerShell or install any app for this).

Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

In the set Folder= part you set the path to the folder where the files are that you want to rename. I recommend testing this on copys first to see if the result is as expected...
@echo off

:: set folder where the files to rename are:
set Folder=Teste 01

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%Folder%\*.*"') do (
                                                      Set "Name=%%~na"
                                                      Call :Rename "%%~a"
                                                     )
pause
exit

:Rename
ren "%Folder%\%~1" "%Name:~4%%~x1"
goto :EOF

https://youtu.be/mtmywBg5tag

Thank you Ricardo. Unfortunately it did not work for me. But I have to check if i didn't make an error.

@Erwinneke uut Bels: are you sure all of your files have 4 or more characters? In the set Folder= part did you put the full path to the folder where the files are?

I added a video to the answer.
